# Using 1 Controller in 2 layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logic, social-networking

I have a logic question and I cannot figure out how to do it. First of all, I am working on an social networking site, and I completed the site in pure PHP, but now I am re-writing the backend in rails.

My questions is, I generated UsersController, it has new, create, show, edit, update, delete, and destroy.

I thought I could use "new" to display sign up page, "create" to process sign up, "show" to display profile page, "edit" to display account settings and "update" to process edit.

I might have a logic problem here, maybe I should put "new" and "create" in a signup controller. This where I get confused. The problem with the first logic I said, I have 2 layouts, one of them is for before login, and the other one is for after login. (You can imagine Facebook's header before login, and after login).

So, when I have 2 different layout, I cannot use 1 controller in 2 layout. Because sign up page has "before login header design" and account settings and profile has "after login header design". And as you can guess I define layout in controller.

I don't know if I explained well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using 1 controller in 2 layouts, I decided to use separate controllers. So, I have profile_controller, which has "edit" and "update" for account settings and "show" to display profile. And I also users_controller, which has followings: login, login_attempt, signup, signup_attempt, etc..

So, I am not putting signup and edit together in 1 controller, instead using 2 different controllers is much better and clean, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Rails will look-up a layout with the same name as the controller, or else application.html.erb. But you can also specify one controller-wide (which won't help you, but bear with me)

```
class SomethingController
  layout "some_name"
  ...
```

That's still layout-wide, so not what you need.

But you can also specify a specific layout on each call to `render` in an action:

```
def edit
   #some logic
   render "some_template", :layout => "some_layout"
end
```

Or, to take the default template lookup, but still specify a layout:

```
def edit
   # some logic
   render :layout => "some_layout"
end
```

There's another way you can specify layouts too, which might be especially appropriate for the use case of "one layout if not logged in, another if logged in":

```
class SomeController
   layout :method_name_to_determine_layout

   # ... actions ...

   protected
   def method_name_to_determine_layout
     if current_user
        "logged_in_layout_name"
     else
        "not_logged_in_layout_name"
     end
   end
```

You can learn more about the different ways to specify layouts in the [Layouts and Rendering Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: you're welcome, if you feel it answers your question please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rails has basic CRUD default actions. Additionally each action can have different processing depending on the HTTP verb. You can also add custom actions & routes.

It is best to follow standard Rails practices for each default action. For example, "new" action should route to the form to create a new user when accessed via GET. An HTTP POST to the form should route to the "create" action.

If you need to add an additional controller action, do so with a custom method. Again, I stress, simple CRUD actions should follow normal Rails conventions.

Read more about [routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)
Read this guide many times to understand [simple CRUD actions in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to roll your own authentication.

I'd recommend using [`Devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)... [great tutorial here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise):

[image]

The reason for this is two-fold.

**Firstly**, Devise gives you the ability to split your app between authenticated and non-authenticated users. Namely, it provides the [`user_signed_in?`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers), [`devise_controller?`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#devise_controller%3F-instance_method) and [`current_user`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) helpers to aid with this.

This might not appear like a big deal, but it will actually help you with your layouts (I'll describe more in a second).

**Secondly**, Devise is pre-rolled. Your questions about how to handle `signups` and `registrations` have already been solved. Of course, there's nothing preventing you from making your own authentication (Devise is just built on `Warden` after all), but it should give you some ideas on how this has been done already.

---

In regards your original question (about layouts), the other answer is very good (in terms of setting `layouts` per method etc).

To add to it, I would say that you have to remember that Rails is a series of classes. As such, setting the `layout` option in the `controller` is the best way to ensure you're getting the correct one.

Here's [Rails explanation on it](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Layouts.html):

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   layout :your_layout

   private

   def your_layout
      devise_controller? || !user_signed_in? ? "new_user" : "application"
   end
end
```

I've found it better to keep your logic as terse as possible. IE only have one set of logic for the layout. We tend to keep it in the `ApplicationController`, overriding where necessary.

--

Finally, your questions also highlighted a base misunderstanding of Rails. I'm not being disrespectful; I've found the clearer your perception of the framework, the better you can work with it:

[image]

You have to remember several key points with Rails:

1. It's an MVC (**M**odel **V**iew **C**ontroller) framework
2. It's built on Ruby; hence is *object orientated*

> maybe I should put "new" and "create" in a signup controller. This where I get confused.

If you take `Devise` as a model, you'll see that you could treat your controllers as layers of abstraction for *objects*. That is, as Devise shows us, you can have `sessions` and `registrations` controllers.

I'm not advocating you do this exactly, I *am* trying to show that if you put the focus onto the *objects* you're working with, it becomes clearer where your controller actions should be placed.

You'll also be best understanding the CRUD (**C**reate **R**ead **U**pdate **D**estroy) nature of Rails controllers & objects. The standard Rails controller is set up as such:

[image]

Whilst this is not strict, it *does* give you another indication as to the structure your controllers should adhere to.

You may know this stuff already!